# How is $L = \{ a^{i}b^{j}c^{k} \space | \space 0 \le i \le j \le k \}$ not a CFL?

Tags: context-free-grammar

The string $a^{i}b^{j}c^{k}$ could be generated by the following grammar:

$$
S \rightarrow SSS \space | \space aS \space | \space bS \space | \space cS \space | \space a \space | \space b \space | \space c
$$

by the below derivation:

$$
S \rightarrow {\bf aS }SS \space \space \space \space (i - 1) \space times\\
S \rightarrow a^{i - 1}{\bf a}SS\\ 
S \rightarrow a^{i}{\bf bS }S \space \space \space \space (j - 1) \space times\\
S \rightarrow a^{i}b^{j-1}{\bf b}S\\ 
S \rightarrow a^{i}b^{j}{\bf cS} \space \space \space \space (k - 1) \space times\\
S \rightarrow a^{i}b^{j}c^{k-1}{\bf c}\\ 
S \rightarrow a^{i}b^{j}c^{k}\\ 
$$

However, using the pumping lemma, this has been proved to be non-CFL. Why wouldn't the above derivation work? What have I misunderstood here?

Comment: Is there some way to place those comments (i-1) times, etc. more separated from the "equations"? I couldn't figure out any way to do this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a\equiv a^{1}b^{0}c^{0}$ is not in the grammar. However, according
to your derivation, it is. Your derivation and the grammar do not
agree.

Comment: Uhm, couldn't we just add an $ S \rightarrow \epsilon $ rule? Sorry for this basic question, I am new to this and basically self-learning without any expert guidance.

Comment: But that would still accept $a$, which is clearly not in the grammar (i.e. it is not in the form $a^ib^jc^k$ with $i\leq j\leq k$).

Comment: Oh, I got it now. Thanks.